# Error React Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs, graphql

En este fragmento de codigo estaba intentando lo que es cerrarsesion y remover el token limpiando el localstorage pero en este caso me salta error en la linea 13  
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

```
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloConsumer } from 'react-apollo';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const cerrarSesionUsuario = (cliente, history) => {
    localStorage.removeItem('token', '');
    //desloguear
    cliente.resetStore();
    //redireccionar
    history.push('/login');
}
const CerrarSesion = ({history}) => {
    <ApolloConsumer>
    { cliente=>{
        return (
            <button
                onClick={() => cerrarSesionUsuario(cliente, history)} 
                className="btn btn-danger ml-md-2 mt-2 mt-md-0">
                Cerrar Sesión
            </button>   
        );
    } }
    </ApolloConsumer>
}

export default withRouter(CerrarSesion);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu problema esta en la declaracion:

```
<ApolloConsumer>
    { cliente=>{
        return (
            <button
                onClick={() => cerrarSesionUsuario(cliente, history)} 
                className="btn btn-danger ml-md-2 mt-2 mt-md-0">
                Cerrar Sesión
            </button>   
        );
    } }
    </ApolloConsumer>
}
```

Intenta con:

```
const CerrarSesion = ({history}) => {
    <ApolloConsumer>
    { (cliente=>{
        return (
            <button
                onClick={() => cerrarSesionUsuario(cliente, history)} 
                className="btn btn-danger ml-md-2 mt-2 mt-md-0">
                Cerrar Sesión
            </button>   
        );
    })()
 }
    </ApolloConsumer>
}
```

---

Cuando dices `cliente =>` es porque estas declarando una funcion, pero el bloque `{ .. }` no espera una funcion como resultado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
client => { console.log(0); }

client();
```

Notaras como no puedo ejecutar client porque estoy creando una funcion anonima, sin asignarla a ninguna variable. Para que funcione debes asignar la referencia de la funcion en una variable o auto ejecutarla:

```js
var fn = client =>  { console.log(client) } ;
fn('cliente 1'); // asignando la referencia de la funcion para ejecutarla

(client => { console.log(client) })('cliente 2'); // auto eejecutando la funcion
```